# Dependence of tensor network on underlying physical lattice structure

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, lattice-model, tensor-network

I have noticed that the majority of research on tensor networks has focused on lattice systems. For example, [in this review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2164), the author mentions using PEPS on different lattices such as triangular, kagome, etc (Section 5.2 in the link). I understand how the correlations make an *effective lattice*, but I am not sure how this effective "lattice" of tensors is explicitly related or dependent on the underlying physical lattice. Even in [studies of continuous matrix product states](https://vcq.quantum.at/fileadmin/Publications/PhysRevLett.104.190405.pdf), they mention the continuum limit of some lattice parameter $\epsilon$. Why start with a system on the physical lattice in the first place? Any description/references would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be related to tensor networks.  It seems you are asking "Why study lattice models?".  Is that correct?  In that case, you might get a bigger audience by actually asking that.